# OneLogin SCIM 2.0 support for /Groups

Tags: onelogin

All the examples in the documentation use SCIM 1.1. What is the level of support for SCIM 2.0 /Groups?  What are the supported features?

Answer (score 0):

One way to create SCIM Groups is to add users to Roles. Enable Provisioning App in the created role ( apps menu), and then connect between the role and the provisioning app by rule ( attached screen shot with rule example).
Provisioning app would create a group with this name. Important to refresh and reapply the mappings. Scim_demo_5_change is role name on this screenshot.
[image: Scim_demo_5_change is role name.]